# Dart with RIkuloUI. Why is there no output?

Tags: javascript, dart, rikulo

Good evening Coders,

I have a serious problem with Dart and Rikulo_Ui to be more specific the problem only comes with Rikulo_Ui.

I am really a newbie to all Dart stuff so please be gentle and don't hesitate to ask for more infos.

My Problem is that as soon as I try to use Rikulo_ui components I only get to see a white Screen in my browser there is nothing displayed. Really nothing. The code bevore the rikulo part is invoked but the first call of a Rikulo method leads to the white screen error. So for this code:

```
import 'package:rikulo_ui/view.dart';
import 'dart:js' as js;
void main() {
  js.context.callMethod("alert",["Hello"]);
  final welcome = new TextView("Hello World!");
  welcome.profile.location = "center center";
  welcome.on.click.listen((event) {
    welcome.text = "Hi, this is Rikulo.";
    welcome.style.border = welcome.style.border.isEmpty ? "1px solid blue": "";
    welcome.requestLayout(); //need to re-layout since its size is changed
  });
  welcome.addToDocument();
}
```

The alert is invoked perfectly but then I only see a white screen. The developer tools of the dartium browser led me to the following exception:

```
package:rikulo_ui/src/view/view_impls.dart:26 Exception: No static getter 'browser' declared in class '_ViewImpl'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'browser'
Receiver: Type: class '_ViewImpl@107880211'
Arguments: [...]
```

I used pub with the configuration from the tutorial and just added the dependency rikulo_ui and used `pub get` and `pub install`.

The HTML file that should display my code looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="packages/rikulo_ui/css/default/view.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
<script type="application/dart" src="HelloWorld.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The downloaded examples from the Rikulo side exited with the same error. I really just not able to use any Rikulo compoents. I also made sure that Dartium and Dart both have the same version (1.13.0).

Thank you for your help!

Regards,
Torsten

Comment: Have you tried to open the same Url from Chrome or Firefox? It could be a Dartium issue?  Dartium is currently heavily reworked.

Comment: Hi Günter, yes I did, in Chrome and Firefox (and IE) I get no output for dart scripts at all. So Dartium seems to be my only possibility to run native dart scrips. I allready tried to compile it to js. It did not work as well

Comment: Here we go: https://github.com/HopfTorsten/DartRikuloTest Thank you @GünterZöchbauer for your help!

Comment: I investigated quite a while but I have no clue yet what the problem is. DartAnalyzer breaks down with this project (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25030). WebStorms find functions has troubles finding source code in this project (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19220).

Comment: Is it right that you could reproduce the error with the project or did i misunderstand something?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I have no idea why it doesn't produce better errors. I have no clue what could lead to this weird behavior. Lets hope someone from the Dart team takes a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upgrade to the latest Rikulo UI (0.8.0). I fixed some incompatibility issues for the latest SDK.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue.

Comment: At the end I want to inform you, that I did not use Rikulo, because not only this part wasn't working for a long time, but also because the Rikulo_Gap API wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions not related to the problem related in your question but spare you some more issues when trying out Dart:

For all tools to work properly you should stick with the Pub package layout convention https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html

- in a GitHub repository, the `pubspec.yaml` file should be at the top-level (no `Dart` subdirectory). This doesn't matter in this case but prevents to add the repository as a dependency in `pubspec.yaml`. https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html#git-packages
- the web entry pages should be in the `web` top-level directory. This is more important.
- just a Dart style guide recommendation: only use lowercase and underscore in file and package names. This ensures everything runs well on all operating systems.
- add concrete version constraints instead of `none` or `any`. This often leads to unexpected old package versions when published old packages have no proper constraints itself, which sometimes happens these old versions are picked if there are resolution conflicts with recent packages because of incompatible constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the help and style guides!

Comment: I don't know how to progress with your main issue. It's quite weird that this little code causes that much troubles. I'm on bleeding edge and the Dart Analyzer has a few known issues here. I hope you understand that I don't want start fiddling with different Dart versions for this. If I have another idea I'll take another look and add a comment.